# Stop concurrent php jobs jobs run via cron job

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron, queue

I'm using Queuesadilla job queue plugin for CakePhp to manage several heavy duty tasks as data extraction from excel and so. I run the shell command with a cron job with an interval. However, if there are more than one job listed in the queue; shell command starts the worker on the next job without waiting the previous one's ending or failure. Since I want to run shell command with a very small interval as 5seconds and some of the jobs take 3 mins to run completely; I want worker to wait for the previous job to complete and not start till then.

However when I run a cronjob with `bin/cake CustomQueuesadilla`; obviously it starts with a new PID and so on without knowing if the previous one still running. When I set my worker's runtime as 20seconds and set the cron job interval as 3 minutes; I have a job working every 3 minutes. But this also means if there are no jobs, it will wait 3 minutes - 20 seconds to run again. I want to reduce this time window.

I'm open to architectural changes and different libraries as well.

Comment: Typically a queue worker should always run in the background, you should not have to start it more than once. That way whatever you queue goes on the same queue. Ideally when your cron task triggers it should queue the jobs on the existing queue worker.

Comment: @apokryfos Makes sense. But how can I detect the queue failure and make it start again in that case?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not very experienced with CakePhp or the library you are using. I know that Laravel's queue system puts failures in a `failed_jobs` table and can optionally retry them. Perhaps there's a similar concept here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Queue vs Cron

What you're trying to implement is a looping queue. Cron is only intended for scheduled events.

1. Build your queue manager/worker

   - This worker [calls the other commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html).
   - Such calls should be wrapped in try/catch, as well as checking for exit codes.
   - You should probably log `(time, command [, error])` of every call.
   - Build it as a singleton.
2. Add a cron entry to call a command which gets the Manager (singleton).

   - As a result of singleton pattern, if it stopped, it will start again.
   - Unless you store the state of the queue outside of that Manager (file or db), it may always die at cmd4 for example, and never run subsequent commands.

#### Manager ex

```
class CommandQueueLoop {
    const QUEUE = [
        'app:command1' => [
            'command' => 'app:command1',
        ],
        'app:command2' => [
            'command' => 'app:command2',
            'somearg' => 123
        ],
        'app:command3' => [
            'command' => 'app:command3',
        ],
    ];

    private static $queueManager;

    private $activeQueue;
    private $app;
    private $input;
    private $output;
    private $running;

    public function __construct(Application $app, InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->input = $input;
        $this->output = $output;
        $this->running = false;
        $this->start();
    }

    public static function getInstance(Application $app, InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (!self::$queueManager instanceof self) {
            self::$queueManager = new self();
        }
    }

    public function start(array $queue = null)
    {
        $this->activeQueue = $queue ?? self::QUEUE;
        $this->running = true;
        $this->run($this->activeQueue);
    }

    public function stop()
    {
        $this->running = false;
        $this->activeQueue = null;
    }

    private function run(array $queue)
    {
        if (!$this->running) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($queue as $cmd => $args) {
            $this->call($cmd, $args);
        }

        $this->run($this->activeQueue);
    }

    private function call(string $command, array $args)
    {
        try {
            $cmd = $this->app->find($command);
            $inp = new ArrayInput($args);
            $returnCode = $cmd->run($inp, $this->output);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // log failure
            unset($this->activeQueue[$cmd]); // remove from queue
        }

        // check returnCode & log
    }
}
```

#### Cron Command to ensure Queue is Running

Add this command, and only this command to the cron, once an hour or so. When this runs, if the command has stopped, it will start again.

```
class QueueLoopCommand extends Command
{
    ...

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $queueLoop = CommandQueueLoop::getInstance($this->getApplication(), $input, $output);
    }
}
```

#### Here be dragons

This "manager" needs to be written very carefully, with good logging, and an emergency stop of some kind. Additionally, that Cron Command should be calling host of other methods in the "manager" to check status, last runs, double-check for multiple threads, etc., and do something about unexpected states. Building tools like these get deep fast, and can lead you down rabbit-holes like you wouldn't believe.

Major dangers:

- Memory leaks
- Multiple conflicting threads
- Unintended Race Conditions

Comment: I was trying to avoid using something like supervisor to make code easily managable on different servers but all the suggestions lead sth very similar to yours. So I've checked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately every solution relying on a lock file or a db value is prone to the problem of the php process crashing and thus leaving the lock on.
The only real solution is to build a daemon which is always running a keeps the lock value in memory. The problem is that PHP is a not a good language for creating memory resident applications as with long execution times it inevitably locks up sooner or later because of memory leaks (not even necessarily in your code) or other problems...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).